# How to use SWF as body Background?

Tags: html, css, flash

How to use SWF as body Background in html with css or some other scripts?

```
body {
background-image:url(bg.swf);
background-repeat:repeat; background-position:center top;
}
```

(This is just an example)

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885444/how-to-add-flash-swf-as-background-of-a-html-page

Comment: The link by @Chris will work fine, but with the repeat: I differ my view, as this may not work, as SWF is object that you need to bind using object tag, or using JS file, that need to be done by the same tag properties, and NOT POSSIBLE using `repeat` property.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think would to just set the position of the SWF in your css code so that it will be always behind everything else displayed.

You can use the z-index property for this:

```
.mySWF {
 z-index: -1;
}
```

This creates a class calls "mySWF" which is behind the normal position of everything else. All you need to do is then apply it to the SWF object in your code by adding:

```
class="mySWF"
```

And that will push it behind.